# Many default routes in rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

How do I remove the default routes in Rails 6?

I just installed Rails 6.0.0 and ran 'rails new blog'. I went to take a look at the routes and found a ton of routes (see below). I've tried creating several new projects and they all have the same default routes.

```
$ rake routes

Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                          Controller#Action
        rails_mandrill_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/mandrill/inbound_emails(.:format)                                  action_mailbox/ingresses/mandrill/inbound_emails#create
        rails_postmark_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/postmark/inbound_emails(.:format)                                  action_mailbox/ingresses/postmark/inbound_emails#create
           rails_relay_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/relay/inbound_emails(.:format)                                     action_mailbox/ingresses/relay/inbound_emails#create
        rails_sendgrid_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/sendgrid/inbound_emails(.:format)                                  action_mailbox/ingresses/sendgrid/inbound_emails#create
         rails_mailgun_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/mailgun/inbound_emails/mime(.:format)                              action_mailbox/ingresses/mailgun/inbound_emails#create
       rails_conductor_inbound_emails GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails(.:format)                                 rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#index
                                      POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails(.:format)                                 rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#create
    new_rails_conductor_inbound_email GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/new(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#new
   edit_rails_conductor_inbound_email GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id/edit(.:format)                        rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#edit
        rails_conductor_inbound_email GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#show
                                      PATCH  /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#update
                                      PUT    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#update
                                      DELETE /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#destroy
rails_conductor_inbound_email_reroute POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/:inbound_email_id/reroute(.:format)                      rails/conductor/action_mailbox/reroutes#create
                   rails_service_blob GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                               active_storage/blobs#show
            rails_blob_representation GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format) active_storage/representations#show
                   rails_disk_service GET    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_key/*filename(.:format)                              active_storage/disk#show
            update_rails_disk_service PUT    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token(.:format)                                      active_storage/disk#update
                 rails_direct_uploads POST   /rails/active_storage/direct_uploads(.:format)                                           active_storage/direct_uploads#create
```

I was expecting at most 1 route (index page).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you won't use these features in your project you should run

```
rails new blog --skip-active-storage --skip-action-mailer --skip-action-mailbox
```

There you can see full list of new Rails app options

```
rails new --help
```

By the way: new Rails app doesn't contain any routes by default. See [Rails routing guide](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/967)

Comment: note that action-mailer does not create any route, all routes on the question came from active storage and action mailbox

Answer (score 7):

I just hit this as well.  If you add this code to your `config/application.rb`, it will remove those routes:

```rb
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 6.0

    # CODE YOU SHOULD ADD vvvvvv
    initializer(:remove_action_mailbox_and_activestorage_routes, after: :add_routing_paths) { |app|
      app.routes_reloader.paths.delete_if {|path| path =~ /activestorage/}
      app.routes_reloader.paths.delete_if {|path| path =~ /actionmailbox/ }
    }
    # CODE YOU SHOULD ADD ^^^^^^^^

    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration can go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded after loading
    # the framework and any gems in your application.
  end
end
```

From what I can tell, this uses a private API to access the files that will create these routes and removes them from the path.  I have no idea if this will remove them from production or not, and since it's a private API it'll likely break later, but at least it cleans up the output of `bin/rails routes`.

Comment: Interesting find. Thanks!

Comment: Wow! this work perfectly

Answer (score 6):

You can remove the `actionmailbox` functionality completely from an existing app (if you are upgrading rails or if you already ran `rails new`) by expanding the line in your application.rb file that requires `rails/all`. This file just includes the default `rails` libraries. [Have a look](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/all.rb).

By replacing this line, you'll not only exclude the routes but also prevent your app from loading code that never gets used.

Here's an example, showing the top portion of my `application.rb` file:

```
# config/application.rb

require_relative 'boot'

# Check out what rails/all.rb is currently expanded to:
#  https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/all.rb
# Replace `require 'rails/all'` with just the libs that you want and 
# exclude the rest
require 'active_record/railtie'
# require 'active_storage/engine'
require 'action_controller/railtie'
require 'action_view/railtie'
require 'action_mailer/railtie'
require 'active_job/railtie'
require 'action_cable/engine'
# require 'action_mailbox/engine'
require 'action_text/engine'
require 'rails/test_unit/railtie'
require 'sprockets/railtie'

# the rest of your initialization follows here ...
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess there's no way to do that yet

For the ActiveStorage routes you'll have this config for your config/application.rb

```
config.active_storage.draw_routes = false
```

- https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c6ef71ccf23fcfb73c3cce82d8437a9bcb5bd07c/railties/test/application/configuration_test.rb#L2608, it's not on the current stable release, but it's on the master branch for the next release

For ActionMailbox routes I can't find anything even on the master branch. I guess there will be something like the active_storage config for the next release.

Comment: Thanks, this should help

Comment: Yeah, this helps but still need to remove the others. Great job!

Answer (score 0):

In `config/application.rb` replace this line:

```
require "rails/all"
```

With its content and keep only the rail ties you need:

```
require "rails"

%w(
  active_record/railtie
  active_storage/engine
  action_controller/railtie
  action_view/railtie
  action_mailer/railtie  <-- REMOVE THIS!
  active_job/railtie
  action_cable/engine
  action_mailbox/engine  <-- REMOVE THIS!
  action_text/engine
  rails/test_unit/railtie
  sprockets/railtie
).each do |railtie|
  begin
    require railtie
  rescue LoadError
  end
end
```

Then remove any mail related config from `config/environments/*.rb`

Comment: Not Work, at least in my computer